# Does there exist a UDF to convert from Easting, Northing to latitude, longitude within BigQuery?

Tags: r, google-bigquery, udf

I've got a load of Easting, Northing points using the BNG system within BigQuery.

Normally I read them into r and then convert (from CRS("+init=epsg:27700") to CRS("+init=epsg:4326")).

Is it possible to actually use a UDF to do this within BigQuery?

There's JS code here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html to do the conversion.

How would I actually go about turning this into a UDF, in particular then being able to use the UDF within bigrquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make use of this JavaScript code in a UDF, you can:

- Store a copy of the JavaScript files that you want to use on [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).
- [Enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) for your query.
- In the query itself, use `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION` to define the UDF. Use the `OPTIONS` clause and specify the [`library` paths](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries) that you want to load.

The final query would look something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ConvertCoordinate(input STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS
"""
    // Assumes 'jsConvertCoordinate' is defined in one of the library files.
    return jsConvertCoordinate(input);
"""
OPTIONS (
  library="gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib1.js",
  library="gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib2.js"
);

SELECT ConvertCoordinate(coordinate) AS converted_coordinate
FROM MyTable;
```